# Subjective behavior regarding to which question are immediately closed

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, closing

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760043/active-beautiful-fields-of-mathematics) question. Immediately there were votes cast to close it and it several people downvoted it (although some also voted it up).

But my question is no more subjective than [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/which-one-result-in-mathematics-has-surprised-you-the-most?rq=1) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832223/what-was-the-book-that-opened-your-mind-to-the-beauty-of-mathematics) one; moreover, it's a question along the same lines!

But these questions were wildly successful generating lots of nice answers" and stayed open for a long time.

Why are people so "trigger happy" to close my question? It seems somewhat unfair, in comparison to the fact that these other questions stayed open for month.
 I believe, as it is along the same lines as these other questions, but fills a void these questions haven't covered, it might also attract nice answers from knowledgeable people, so by closing it some nice answers might be lost to the math.SE network! And why would you want to do that?

Comment: Your questions can only stand on their own merit. The voting behaviour on other questions can never serve as a justification for your question to remain open.

Comment: Standards have evolved. Back in the day the community was more lenient with such questions. Nowadays they get closed quickly, and old questions that don't meet the new standards get closed too. Such is life. There are other websites, consider asking your question elsewhere. Having your question closed on math.SE is not the end of the world.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Not the end of the world, but its annoying, as math.SE is the biggest site for these questions which would have generated the best answers. Thus, I'll have to personally wait until I can chat about this stuff with professors at my department, which will take infinitely longer - and the answers won't be finding their way into public internet.

Answer (score 8):

Voters may have been thinking of, for example, the first bullet point of the [don't ask FAQ guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which such questions often fall under. The reason we exclude these (I think) is that content like that is not really very useful and it tends to multiply. The web is full of top ten lists for beauty and interest and we don't really want to get on that bandwagon anymore.

Of course, this wasn't always the case, and such questions have prospered in the past. We generally acknowledge that it's unreasonable to apply today's standards rigidly to our predecessors' decisions, so some continue to stand.

Even then, some fresh questions like this can sometimes cling to life. Usually it is because of some other mitigating circumstance which does not apply to many questions.

The process we have in place attempts to throttle and check unreasonable closure behavior by spreading the decision out. It may not be perfect, but it is better than most alternatives.

Comment: I understand. But I want to point out that actually, the web is *not* fully of top ten lists for beauty and interest in the specific way I asked for. Or can you give, say, 5 links without much looking around ?

Comment: @temo I just don't see how your request differs significantly from them. I don't understand the second half of the comment. At any rate, you can see how it can be objected to on grounds of subjectivity